# Having troubles with nested while loops

Tags: c, while-loop, nested-loops

The goal is to assign the average to different players based on their uniform number. The problem is that it keeps skipping the second printf and the characters from the switch statement aren't working. I'm sure it's a pretty simple error on my part, but I just can't seem to find it.

```
int main(){
float ab;
float hits;
int un;
char pa;
printf("Please enter the player number, or -1 to exit. \n");
scanf("%d%*c \n", &un);
while( un!= -1)
{
    printf("Please enter either an H for a hit or an O for a out, enter E to stop. \n");
    scanf("%c%*c", &pa);
    while(pa != 'E')
    {
            switch (pa) 
            {
            case 'h':
            case 'H': 
                ab += 1;
                hits +=1;
                break;

            case 'o':
            case 'O': 
                ab+=1;
                break;

            default:
                printf("Error: Please insert an O or H \n");
                break;
            }
        float average = (ab/hits);
        printf("Player %d's score is equal to: %d \n", un, average);

        printf("Please enter the player number, or -1 to exit. \n");

        scanf("%d%*c \n", &un);
    }

}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using values of uninitialized variables `ab` and `hits`, which have automatic storage duration, invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Passing `average`, whose type is `float`, to `%d` in`printf()`, which calls for data with type `int`, also invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Are you sure the second `printf()` is skipped? (being skipped is possible due to undefined behavior) Isn't it just not called yet because the first `scanf()` is waiting for non-whitespace character?

Comment: the posted code seems to be using tabs for indenting.  Never use tabs for indenting because each wordprocessor/editor has the tab stops/tab width set differently.    Always use spaces for indenting.  Suggest using 4 spaces for each indent level as that is wide enough to be visible even with variable width fonts and enables many indent levels across the page.

Comment: regarding this line: `printf("Player %d's score is equal to: %d \n", un, average);` the compiler outputs a warning: foramt '%d' expects argument of type 'int', but argument 3 has type 'double' [-Wformat=].   Suggest changing to: `printf("Player %d's score is equal to: %f \n", un, average);`

Answer (score 0):

Your loop nesting wasn't quite correct, your `scanf` calls would hang, you needed to preinitialize `ab` and `hits`, and your final `printf` had an incorrect format.

Here's the corrected code [please pardon the gratuitous style cleanup]:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main()
{
    float ab;
    float hits;
    int un;
    char pa;

    while (1) {
        printf("Please enter the player number, or -1 to exit.\n");
#if 0
        scanf("%d%*c \n", &un);
#else
        scanf(" %d", &un);
#endif
        if (un == -1)
            break;

        ab = 0;
        hits = 0;

        printf("Please enter either an H for a hit or an O for a out, enter E to stop.\n");
        while (1) {
#if 0
            scanf("%c%*c", &pa);
#else
            scanf(" %c", &pa);
#endif
            if ((pa == 'E') || (pa == 'e'))
                break;

            switch (pa) {
            case 'h':
            case 'H':
                ab += 1;
                hits += 1;
                break;

            case 'o':
            case 'O':
                ab += 1;
                break;

            default:
                printf("Error: Please insert an O or H\n");
                break;
            }
        }

        float average = (ab / hits);

#if 0
        printf("Player %d's score is equal to: %d\n", un, average);
#else
        printf("Player %d's score is equal to: %g\n", un, average);
#endif
    }

    return 0;
}
```